# Foreach loop for ls output

Tags: shell, ls, filenames, wildcards, for

I am trying to process some files in directory using foreach loop for ls output:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(ls -1Atu); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

At first time i thought it works, but when i created file with name like `*` or `filename*`, shell add additional iterations, because `*` interpreted as wild char.
But if I escape ls output like `for i in "$(ls -1Atu)";`, I'll get a single iteration, and $i will contain the output from ls entirely.
How can we solve this problem? I should note that any variants with `ls -1Atu` preferable, as I need, what would the resulting files were sorted by atime.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background reading: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Setting `IFS` to a newline means that only newlines, and not spaces and tabs, will be treated as separators during the expansion of the command substitution. Your method will not support file names that contain newlines; this is a fundamental limitation of `ls`¹.

Furthermore, and this is what you ran against, setting `IFS` has no effect on the other thing that happens on the expansion of a command substitution, which is globbing (wildcard matching). You can turn off globbing, and then your script will work as long as file names don't contain newlines.

```
IFS='
'
set -- *"$IFS"*
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
  echo >&2 "There are file names with newlines. I cannot cope with this."
  exit 2
fi
set -f
for i in $(ls -1Atu); do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
set +f
unset IFS
```

The easy, reliable way to enumerate files by date is to use something other than a pure Bourne-style shell, such as zsh which has [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to modify the way wildcard matches are sorted.

```
#!/bin/zsh
files_by_access_time=(*(Doa))
```

¹  <sub>You can work around it with some `ls` implementations, but not if you need portability.</sub>

Comment: @muru Fixed. You are encouraged to edit posts to edit obvious mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

For various reasons related to whitespace issues, etc., it is not advisable to [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). An alternative, which uses GNU versions of `find`, `sort`, `sed`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%A@ %f\0" | 
  sort -rnz | 
  sed -z 's/^[0-9.]\+ //'
```

- `find` is, of course, much more flexible than `ls` when it comes to listing and filtering files, but it doesn't do sorting by itself.
- Here, I print the modification time in seconds (`%A@`), followed by the filename and an ASCII NUL character, the only safe character for delimiting filenames.
- `sort -rnz` then takes in the NUL-delimited input (`-z`) and sorts numerically (`-n`), in descending order (since `-t` of `ls` gives newest first).
- Then I used `sed` to strip off the initial time, again dealing in NUL-delimited lines (`-z`).

The resulting output is a stream of NUL-delimited lines. In bash (not in plain sh), you can then read them into variables by:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%A@ %f\0" | 
  sort -rnz | 
  sed -z 's/^[0-9.]\+ //' |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
  do 
    # do stuff with filenames
    printf "%s\n" "$filename"
  done
```

This is, of course, somewhat more complicated, but considerably safer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
ls -1Atu | while IFS= read -r entry; do
    echo "$entry"
done
```

With this example, the output is generated once, and the `while read entry` section causes the output from `ls` to be parsed line-by-line, which solves the issue with your `for` example where everything was getting placed in `$i` in a single round.

Comment: why so many options with `ls`? It's sufficient to write just `ls`. To be safe with other issues you should better write: `ls | while IFS= read -r entry ; do printf "%s\n" "$entry" ; done`.

Comment: The options for `ls` were specified by the OP because they want to show hidden files/folders and they want a specific sorting rule.  The `1` is unnecessary but doesn't hurt.  I've added the `-r` to my answer.  Can you explain how the `IFS=` helps in this case?

Comment: ah, I missed that the OP was the source of those `ls` options. - Nonetheless, they are all superfluous, aren't they?! - The purpose of `IFS` is to prevent the trimming of whitespace from the front or rear of the names that are read by `read`; it's just a standard code pattern if you want your input unchanged. The same with using `printf` instead of `echo`; just a safety measure to make the code more robust.

Comment: @Janis: "superfluous"?  Huh?  As jkt123 acknowledged, `-1` is unnecessary when the output from `ls` is not going to a terminal, but `-A` tells `ls` to include `.` files, `-t` tells it to sort by date/time instead of name, and `-u` tells it to sort by access time instead of mod time.  OK, `-tu` might be equivalent to `-u` in the absence of `-l` (lowercase `L`), but, if the OP cares about order, these options are not superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you really mean adding `*` in filename?
2. Or you mean the output of `ls` gives filename ending in `*` if it has execute permission?

If only output problem of `ls`, you could simply solve by:

replace `ls` to `\ls`, this is to use un-aliased version of `ls`, which doesn't output `*`