# Returning last-written file, containing particular sub-string in file name?

Tags: files, filesystems, logs, alias

Whilst monitoring logging I have to go to my log files, order by written date, so I can then see the name of the log file for the most-recent execution of my application.

Is there any way, given a directory and sub-string, to return the name of the file containing that sub-string, which was most-recently written to?

So if I had

```
AFile1.log (last written 9am)
AFile2.log (last written 10am)
```

and I wanted to return the most recent log containing the file name "AFile", it'd return AFile2.log?

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198037/70524) deals with looping over a list of files ordered by modification time. My answer and Gilles' answer can be extended reasonably easily to deal with filenames matching some pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Whilst monitoring logging I have to go to my log files, order by written date, so I can then see the name of the log file for the most-recent execution of my application.

I assume this means that the application writes log files like this:

- AFile1.log
- AFile2.log
- AFile3.log
- AFile*x*.log

> Is there any way, given a directory and sub-string, to return the name of the file containing that sub-string, which was most-recently written to?

I assume this sub-string is the partial file name, AFile, and not a string to find within a log file.

> I wanted to return the most recent log containing the file name "AFile", it'd return AFile2.log?

From the manual on `ls` (`man ls`):

```
-t     sort by modification time, newest first
-l     use a long listing format
```

So, to first see this in action, we might use `ls -lt` to get a long directory listing with the newest modification first.

```
$ ls -lt AFile*.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27254 May 23 09:00 AFile2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29599 May 22 21:15 AFile1.log
```

Good. This works. (We know we do not want the long listing; we are just using `-l` to witness that the desired output is correct.) Now, how do we grab just the first line? If we do not know how to do this, the use of `apropos` is often beneficial. So let's try it.

```
$ apropos "first"
```

Among the many lines of output, we see the following:

```
head (1)             - output the first part of files
```

Ok, so let's look at the man page for `head` (`man head` or `man 1 head`).

```
-n, --lines=[-]K
print  the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the lead‐
ing '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

Connecting the dots, and using a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), we get the latest file.

```
$ ls -t AFile*.log | head -n 1
AFile2.log
```

The pipe is the construct using the `|` character, which passes the output of `ls -t AFile*.log` to `head -n 1`.